# When running "Grunt" in the terminal errors in local

Tags: gruntjs

When running grunt in my terminal I keep having the issue of the below.

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
Error: Unable to read "environments-local.yaml" file (Error code: ENOENT).
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I have run npm install and sudo npm install with no success.

Has anyone else had the same problem? And if so how did you overcome it?

Please let me know if you need to know any more information

Many thanks

Comment: Does the `environments-local.yaml` file exist? And does it have read permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up a local environment and it works fine